# Pathing issues in rails form_with for associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, parameter-passing, associations, facade

I am working on a project for which I have to analyse data inside a file, which the user should be able to upload. I have a model InputFile and chose to implement an analysis_facade for my Analysis model which bundles most of the functionality. 
Here are the models

```
#app/models/analysis.rb
class Analysis < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :input_file, dependent: :destroy
end

#app/models/input_file.rb
class InputFile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :analysis
  has_many :access_data, dependent: :destroy

  def uploaded_file=(file_field)
    self.name = File.basename(file_field.original_filename).gsub(/[^\w._-]/,'')
    self.content_type = file_field.content_type.chomp
    self.data = file_field.read
  end
end
```

Here comes my AnalysisController and the corresponding facade pattern

```
#app/controllers/analyses_controller.rb
class AnalysesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_analysis, only: :show

  def show
    @analysis_facade = AnalysisFacade.new(@analysis)
  end

  private

  def set_analysis
    @analysis ||= Analysis.create
  end
end

#app/facades/analysis_facade.rb
class AnalysisFacade
  attr_reader :analysis

  def initialize(analysis)
    @analysis = analysis
  end

  def new_input_file
    @input_file = analysis.build_input_file
  end

  def input_file
    @input_file ||= new_input_file
  end

  def access_data
    @access_data ||= analysis.input_file.access_data
  end
end
```

My controller for InputFiles

```
#app/controllers/input_files_controller.rb
class InputFilesController < ApplicationController
  include LogFileScanner

  before_action :set_analysis, only: [:new, :create, :update]

  def new
    @input_file = Input_file.new
  end

  def create
    @input_file = @analysis.build_input_file(input_file_params)
    if @input_file.save
      access_data = scan(@input_file.data)
      @input_file.access_data.create(access_data)
    end
  end

  def update
    @input_file = @analysis.input_file
    if @input_file.update
      access_data = scan(@input_file.data)
      @input_file.access_data.update(access_data)
    end
  end

  private

  def input_file_params
    params.require(:input_file).permit(:uploaded_file, :analysis_id)
  end

  def set_analysis
    @analysis = Analysis.find(params[:input_file][:analysis_id])
  end
end
```

For the file upload I have these views

```
#app/views/analyses/show.html.erb
<%= render template: 'input_files/get' %>

#app/views/input_files/get.html.erb
<%= form_with model: [@analysis_facade.analysis, @analysis_facade.input_file], action: :update, html: {multipart: true, class: 'form-horizontal center'} do |form| %>
  <div class='form-group.new'>
    <% if false %>
      <%= form.hidden_field :analysis_id, value: @analysis_facade.analysis[:id] %>
    <% end %>
    <%= form.file_field 'uploaded_file' %>
    <%= form.submit "Upload", class: 'btn btn-default btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Executing this results in error

```
undefined method `analysis_input_files_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007f1208040288>:0x00007f11f0d71d48>
Did you mean?  analysis_path
```

for this loc

```
<%= form_with model: [@analysis_facade.analysis, @analysis_facade.input_file], action: :update, html: {multipart: true,
class: 'form-horizontal center'} do |form| %>
```

Why is that? I need to pass the analysis_id to params in order to create the new InputFile. But I want it to be cleaner than manually adding a hidden_field, since model_with should provide this feature. What do I miss here?

Also: Why does rails search for `analysis_input_files_path'? Its clearly a has_one relation, so shouldn't it look for analysis_input_file_path then?

EDIT:

```
#bin/rails routes

                     Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                           Controller#Action
                   analyses GET    /analyses(.:format)                                   analyses#index
                            POST   /analyses(.:format)                                   analyses#create
               new_analysis GET    /analyses/new(.:format)                               analyses#new
              edit_analysis GET    /analyses/:id/edit(.:format)                          analyses#edit
                   analysis GET    /analyses/:id(.:format)                               analyses#show
                            PATCH  /analyses/:id(.:format)                               analyses#update
                            PUT    /analyses/:id(.:format)                               analyses#update
                            DELETE /analyses/:id(.:format)                               analyses#destroy
     input_file_access_data GET    /input_files/:input_file_id/access_data(.:format)     access_data#index
                            POST   /input_files/:input_file_id/access_data(.:format)     access_data#create
new_input_file_access_datum GET    /input_files/:input_file_id/access_data/new(.:format) access_data#new
          edit_access_datum GET    /access_data/:id/edit(.:format)                       access_data#edit
               access_datum GET    /access_data/:id(.:format)                            access_data#show
                            PATCH  /access_data/:id(.:format)                            access_data#update
                            PUT    /access_data/:id(.:format)                            access_data#update
                            DELETE /access_data/:id(.:format)                            access_data#destroy
                input_files GET    /input_files(.:format)                                input_files#index
                            POST   /input_files(.:format)                                input_files#create
             new_input_file GET    /input_files/new(.:format)                            input_files#new
            edit_input_file GET    /input_files/:id/edit(.:format)                       input_files#edit
                 input_file GET    /input_files/:id(.:format)                            input_files#show
                            PATCH  /input_files/:id(.:format)                            input_files#update
                            PUT    /input_files/:id(.:format)                            input_files#update
                            DELETE /input_files/:id(.:format)                            input_files#destroy
              analyses_show GET    /
```

Answer (score 0):

I was a conceptional mistake. I changed the facade model to

```
class AnalysisFacade

  attr_reader :analysis

  def initialize(analysis)
    @analysis = analysis
  end

  def new_input_file
    @analysis.build_input_file
  end

  def input_file
    @analysis.input_file ||= new_input_file
  end

  def access_data
    @analysis.input_file.access_data
  end

end
```

And the view works now like this

```
<%= form_with model: @analysis_facade.input_file, html: {multipart: true, class: 'form-horizontal center'} do |form| %>
  <div class='form-group.new'>
    <%= form.file_field 'uploaded_file' %>
    <%= form.submit "Upload", class: 'btn btn-default btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```